# properties - non public weak setter appears to work, but getter only returns the same value as first call

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

Using properties I want a publicly visible getter and a privately visible setter for a object with weak reference.   I thought that I had something that worked using a class extension.  Well that is until I called the getter, both, before and after the setting the object to nil.  The getter worked if I called only before or after the object is set to nil.  Here is what I have:

---

### Bar.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Bar : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly, weak) NSObject *object;  // note only readonly
- (id) initWithObject:(NSObject *)object;
@end
```

---

### Bar.m

```
#import "Bar.h"

@interface Bar ()  // class extension
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, weak) NSObject *object;  // note readwrite
@end

@implementation Bar

- (id) initWithObject:(NSObject *)object
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.object = object;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

---

### main.c

```
#import "Bar.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        // Call getter once, before setting the object to nil.
        // This appears to work.
        NSObject *object1 = [[NSObject alloc] init];
        Bar *bar1 = [[Bar alloc] initWithObject:object1];
        NSLog(@"before      - bar1.object[%p] object1[%p]",bar1.object, object1);

        // Call getter once, after setting the object to nil.
        // This appears to work.
        NSObject *object2 = [[NSObject alloc] init];
        Bar *bar2 = [[Bar alloc] initWithObject:object2];
        object2 = nil;
        NSLog(@"after       - bar2.object[%p] object2[%p]",bar2.object, object2);

        // Call getter twice, before and after setting the object to nil.
        // This appears to work to work for the first call to the getter.
        NSObject *object3 = [[NSObject alloc] init];
        Bar *bar3 = [[Bar alloc] initWithObject:object3];
        NSLog(@"both before - bar3.object[%p] object3[%p]",bar3.object, object3);
        object3 = nil;
        NSLog(@"both after  - bar3.object[%p] object3[%p]",bar3.object, object3);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

### Results

```
before      - bar1.object[0x9623030] object1[0x9623030]
after       - bar2.object[0x0] object2[0x0]
both before - bar3.object[0x7523d90] object3[0x7523d90]
both after  - bar3.object[0x7523d90] object3[0x0]
```

I expected that for `both after` to be: `both after  - bar3.object[0x0] object3[0x0]` .

It appears that the weak reference is not being set to `nil` when the getter is called prior to setting the object to `nil` and the again calling it again after.

Comment: Fun fact, this only happens with clang's optimization level set to -O0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the getter before, the weak property is being loaded and converted to a strong reference, which is then being autoreleased. When you call it again after, `object3` is `nil` as expected, but the original object it referenced is still alive, sitting in the autorelease pool. Therefore `bar3.object` still has a valid object to return to you.

Try the following instead:

```
NSObject *object3 = [[NSObject alloc] init];
Bar *bar3 = [[Bar alloc] initWithObject:object3];
@autoreleasepool {
    NSLog(@"both before - bar3.object[%p] object3[%p]",bar3.object, object3);
}
object3 = nil;
NSLog(@"both after  - bar3.object[%p] object3[%p]",bar3.object, object3);
```

Comment: So that is what I suspected. The stack has a strong reference that will eventually be autoreleased, but has not by the time to the second call to `bar3.object`.

Comment: @mmorris: Well, no. The stack has already autoreleased it. The autorelease pool has a reference to the object that won't go away until the pool is drained.